# I can't install jsonschema with pipenv

Tags: python, jsonschema, pipenv

I am trying to install jsonschema with pipenv with the command:

```
python3.8 -m pipenv install jsonschema
```

or directly:

```
pipenv install jsonschema
```

and it returns the following error:

```
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed! 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 857, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 843, in main
    _main(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 822, in _main
    resolve_packages(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 741, in resolve_packages
    from pipenv.utils.internet import create_mirror_source, replace_pypi_sources
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pipenv.utils.internet'; 'pipenv.utils' is not a package
```

If I install it directly with pip install I have no problem, in case it helps.

If someone help me I would appreciate it

Comment: have you tried reinstalling pipenv? it looks like it wasn’t correctly installed. Also what is in the file /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pipenv/utils.py ?

Comment: Yes, I reinstalled, but nothing

Comment: there’s nothing in that file?